# ngx-color-picker Dependency

Tags: html, css, angular, angular5, color-picker

Hi i try to install the ngx-color-picker :

```
ngx-color-picker --save
```

But i have this results

```
    ngx-color-picker --save
Previa3@4.0.0 F:\Users\valentin.griset\IdeaProjects\Previa3-Front
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@5.2.1
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler-cli@5.2.1
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@5.2.1
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser@5.2.1
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@5.2.1
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-server@2.3.1
+-- ngx-color-picker@5.3.0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY nouislider@11.0.3
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY zone.js@0.8.20
```

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

you are missing the "npm install".

```
npm install ngx-color-picker --save
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Please use one of the following:

1. npm install ngx-color-picker --save
              or
2. npm i ngx-color-picker --save